# jdbc connectivity error with hive2

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, odbc, bigdata

I am trying to test connectivity to hive2 using jdbc. But i am getting an authentication failled error where the credentials are correct.

The error I get is:

> java -cp .:/users/apps/ewbeiu/wbeeappp/HiveJdbcClient/* HiveJdbcClient
>   SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. Not able to connect to database pls check your settings
>   java.sql.SQLException: Could not open connection to
>   jdbc:hive2://edbd.corp.com:10000/wbe: Peer indicated failure: Error
>   validating the login Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at HiveJdbcClient.executeQuery(HiveJdbcClient.java:49)
>           at HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:58)

The complete Code is as Folllows

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class HiveJdbcClient {
    private static final String DRIVER_NAME = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
    private static final String HIVE_URL = "jdbc:hive2://edabd.xyz.com:10000/wbe";
    private static final String HIVE_UNAME = "xyz";
    private static final String HIVE_PWD = "Pec7";
    private static Connection con;

    private HiveJdbcClient() {
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
            try {
                    if (con == null) {
                            synchronized (HiveJdbcClient.class) {
                                    if (con == null) {
                                            Class.forName(DRIVER_NAME);
                                            con = DriverManager.getConnection(HIVE_URL, HIVE_UNAME,
                                                            HIVE_PWD);
                                            System.out
                                                            .println("Successfuly Connected to database...!");
                                    }
                            }// End of synchronized block.
                    }// End of if block.
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out
                                    .println("Not able to connect to database pls check your settings \n"
                                                    + e);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out
                                    .println("Not able to connect to database pls check your settings \n"
                                                    + e);
            }// End of try-catch block.
            return con;
    }// End of getConnection() Method.

    public static ResultSet executeQuery(String sql) {
            ResultSet set = null;
            try {
                    if (sql != null) {
                            set = getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
                    }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error while executing query " + e);
            }// End of try-catch block.
            return set;
    }// End of executeQuery() Method.

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, SQLException {
            ResultSet res = executeQuery("show tables;");
            while (res.next()) {
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(res.getString(1))
                            //      + String.valueOf(res.getFloat(2)) + '\t'
                            //      + String.valueOf(res.getString(3))
                            );
            }

    }
}


> The drivers in the classpath are as follows:
> 
> httpclient-4.2.5.jar commons-codec-1.4.jar httpcore-4.2.5.jar
> commons-logging-1.1.3.jar libthrift-0.9.0.jar
> hive-common-0.13.0.2.1.2.0-402.jar hive-service-0.13.0.2.1.2.0-402.jar
> hive-jdbc-0.13.0.2.1.2.0-402.jar hadoop-common-2.4.0.2.1.2.0-402.jar
> slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar guava-11.0.2.jar
```